# make QSqlTableModel from QSqlQueryModel

Tags: python, pyqt

Is there a way to make a QSqlTableModel from a QSqlQueryModel, as you know a QSqlTableModel inherits a QSqlQueryModel.

Or do i have to create a new QSqlTableModel, iterate through the QSqlQueryModel and insert the data with "insertRow" and "setData" into the QSqlTableModel?

The problem:

I have got a (abstract) custom widget (my_custom_widget) which contains a QTableView (table_view) to display data in a table. I usually get the data from my SQLite-database with a QSqlTableModel like this:

```
my_model = QSqlTableModel()
my_model.setTable("my_table")
my_model.select()
```

Sometimes i have an additional "where"-clause. Then it looks like this:

```
my_model = QSqlTableModel()
my_model.setTable("my_table")
my_model.setFilter("filter_column='"+filter_str+"'")
my_model.select()
```

The attribute "filter_str" comes from an additional input-widget (e.g. a QLineEdit or a QSpinBox) in my_custom_widget. The user is now able to limit the data in the table_view in my custom widget.

I pass my_model to my_custom_widget to display the data. I have several methods in my_custom_widget to set the layout of the tabel_view (set header label, column-alignment, ...) or calculate with some columns. I use also a QSortFilterProxyModel to realize an extended filter.
Here i use a QSqlTableModel to realize these things.

But now i want to display a complex, cascaded query in my_custom_widget like this:

[image]

In this query it is necessary to set multiple the "where"-clause (in my example 'filter_str'). Because i was not able to realize this by using a QSqlTableModel with 'setFilter', thought i can do it with a QSqlQueryModel like this:

```
my_sql_query_model = QSqlQueryModel()
my_sql_query_model.setQuery("SELECT d1.* FROM "
                             "(SELECT site.id AS id, nr, site.name, "
                             "site_typ.name AS typ, site_size.site_size_from AS year, "
                             "site_size.site_area FROM site "
                             "LEFT JOIN site_size ON site.id = site_size.site_id, "
                             "site_typ ON site_size.site_typ_id = site_typ.id "
                             "WHERE site_size.site_size_from <= "+str(filter_str)+") d1 "
                             "LEFT JOIN (SELECT site.id AS id, nr, site.name, "
                             "site_typ.name AS typ, site_size.site_size_from AS year, "
                             "site_size.site_area FROM site LEFT JOIN site_size "
                             "ON site.id = site_size.site_id, site_typ "
                             "ON site_size.site_typ_id = site_typ.id "
                             "WHERE site_size.site_size_from <= "+str(filter_str)+") d2 "
                             "ON (d1.id = d2.id AND d1.year < d2.year) "
                             "WHERE d2.id IS NULL ORDER BY nr ASC;",
                             db=my_database())
```

This works perfekt when i am working with an ordinary QTableView.
But in my_custom_widget i have several methods that are using a QSqlTableModel and now i would love to pass a QSqlQueryModel to my_custom_widget. This causes several errors.

So i thought, it is possible to make a QSqlTableModel from a QSqlQueryModel (because QSqlTableModel inherits QSqlQueryModel).

Or is it better (as 'Redanium' said in point 3 of the answer) to make a empty QSqlTableModel and fill it with data from my_sql_query_model.

Comment: I don't understand your question, QSqlTableModel is a QSqlQueryModel since it inherits from QSqlQueryModel. I think you have a [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), what is your main objective?

Comment: I made an addition to explain my problem!

Comment: Then replace the QSqlTableModel with the QSqlQueryModel, your question is still not clear and gives me more evidence to suspect that you have an XY problem.

Comment: I did replaced the QSqlTableModel with the QSqlQueryModel. But my custom widget works with e.g. "fieldIndex" from the QSqlTableModel and i get the error "'QSqlQueryModel' object has no attribute 'fieldIndex'". So i wanted to make a QSqlTableModel from my QSqlQueryModel (that would be read only).

Comment: but then simply those missing methods inheriting from QSqlQueryModel or implementing them with QSqlQuery, even your question is confusing since it does not clearly indicate the reason for the change or the limitations, I recommend you clearly explain what you want (the underlying objective), then explain why you think that QSqlQueryModel is the best option for you, show the code you have (MRE) and then let the community point out how to modify your code to reach your background goal either using QSqlQueryModel or another method. Have you read the XY problem link?

Comment: I have now tried to make a better explanation of the problem

Comment: According to what I have read the problem is not in the QSqlQueryModel or in the QSqlTableModel but in your custom view, wouldn't it be better to adapt your custom view to QSqlQueryModel instead of modifying a QSqlQueryModel so that it behaves like a QSqlTableModel? I think that the second will fail because there are many properties (and states) of the private Qt API that you will not be able to modify causing the logic to fail.

Comment: Yes, it sounds like a very good hint! But sometimes i am working with an editable table_view in my_costom_widget and sometimes i am working with a QSqlRelationalTableModel. Is it possible to adapt my costom view to QSqlQueryModel and then pass a QSqlTableModel or a QSqlRelationalTableModel to my_costom_widget. Which method do i have to use?

Comment: You already know my position: You don't believe a frankenstein. Why don't you create a view class that implements generic things between several models and then 2 views that inherit from that view by specializing in those 2 models?

Comment: Yes, thanks a lot, i will try!

Answer (score 0):

The `QSqlQueryModel` class provides a read-only data model for SQL result sets.

However, you can

- use a `QSqlTableModel` instead or
- insert the data to the database first or
- create your own `QAbstractItemModel` which incorporates a `QSqlQueryModel` and allows for adding rows

Answer (score 0):

You should make a view in your SQL database

```
CREATE VIEW AS tableview
SELECT * FROM table
```

From here you can use a regular QSqlTableModel and set the table to the view's name, filtering from your widgets will still work properly.